# How do I check that each element in an array only contains one type of character?

Tags: c#, arrays

For example:

`{1, 1, 11, 1111, 1111111}` This array is **valid** because each element use only digit 1.

And `{11, 101, 1111, 11111}` This array is **not valid** because each element use 0 and 1 digit.

Comment: Is this an array of ints, strings, doubles, ?

Comment: "all elements in an array are same" is completely different to what you described. Are these strings or integers? In decimal or binary? is `{0,00,0000}` valid? What about `{22222, 22, 2}`? `{xxx, xxx, xxx}`?

Comment: Hi Rob, Its Array of ints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var isValid = arr
    .Select(a => a.ToString()) //Call .ToString() on each integer
    .SelectMany(a => a)        //Select each character in the string and flatten
    .Distinct()                //Get only the unique characters
    .Count() <= 1;             //If there are more than 1 unique characters, it's invalid.
```

Comment: It's not necessary to go through the collection. Using `.All` has a better performance.

Comment: @DannyChen Could you elaborate? Where would you use `All` here?

Comment: Hi @Rob Thanks for your answer. Are there any other ways to do it without using Linq query?

Comment: @Rob My fault :P Forgot the { 11, 22, 33 } case. Going through the collection is necessary.

Comment: @Rob I think `.Select` and `.SelectMany` can be merged into one `.SelectMany`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var allSame = source.SelectMany(n => n.ToString()).Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

This gives the correct results for your two inputs.

Comment: This is even true for `{1, 22, 333}`.

Comment: @Ripple OP did not specify whether or not that input is valid - so the answer is correct

Comment: @Ripple - I've updated the answer, but Rob's point is valid.

Comment: @Rob I agree, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

**Invalid**= {111, 222, 333}, {111, 110, 101}. **Valid** = {111, 111}, {222, 222}

```
char c = arr[0].ToString()[0]; //get the first digit to compare
//char c = arr.First().ToString().First()
bool isValid = arr
     .SelectMany(i => i.ToString()) //select all digits as chars
     .All(s => s == c); //compare them to the c char
```

Using only LINQ (Bad performance)

```
bool isValid = arr
     .SelectMany(i => i.ToString()) //select all digits as chars
     .All(s => s == arr.First().ToString().First()); //compare them to the c char
```

The second example will create an `IEnumerable<Char>` for each digit of the `Array` (Bad performance)

## Solution 2

**Invalid**= {111, 110, 101}. **Valid** = {111, 111}, {222, 222}, **{111, 222, 333}**

```
bool isValid = arr
     .SelectMany(i => i.ToString())
     .Distinct()
     .Count() == 1
```